# GoAsync in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to figure out what goAsync() does, but I can't.
I thought this code would not work, but the broadcast works more than 2 minutes.
Can you show me an example where goAsync() gives at least some advantages

```
class GoAsyncReceiver(binding: FragmentReceiverBinding) : BroadcastReceiver() {
    private val bindingRef = WeakReference(binding)
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive")
        val pendingResult = goAsync()
        thread {
            for (i in 0..120) {
                Thread.sleep(1000)
                Log.d(TAG, "$i")
                bindingRef.get()?.root?.post {
                    bindingRef.get()?.goAsyncResult?.text = i.toString()
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "finish")
            pendingResult.finish()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "GoAsyncReceiver"
    }
}
```

Comment: Android doesn’t guarantee your code to be cut off when you fail to use goAsync. If your process is doing other foreground stuff, it probably won’t be. You use goAsync to get the guarantee that it *won’t* be cut off.